# cant remove or access file

Tags: files

I cant delete a directory because a theres a file in it that returns (I'm using `$filename` etc. as placeholder for the actual name(s) in this post):

```
rm: cannot remove $filename: Invalid argument
```

I get the same thing when I try to use `ls` on it. If I use `ls -l` on the directory it's in I get

```
ls: cannot access $filename Invalid argument
total 0
?????????? ? ? ? ?       ? $filename
```

`ls -ld $directory` returns

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 $user(me) $group(mygroup) $date $directory
```

The file is in a remote mounted drive and I can still access and remove files in that same drive.

What would cause this? And how can I delete this file?

Comment: Please add `ls -ld $directory`, replacing `$directory` with the path to the directory holding your problematic filename. Is this directory mounted from a remote?

Comment: it just returns the directory name and yes it is mounted remote.  But I dont have this problem with other files in the same remote drive.

Comment: I did. and which answer?

Comment: Are you $user, or a member of $group when you try to delete the file and directory? Is the remote filesystem CIFS, NFS, or something else (what)?

Comment: yes I am user as to the what the remote file system is Im not sure its just a system I use not own.

Comment: In that case the best place to ask would be your local IT resource

Comment: Figured as much but wasnt sure if it was something I could fix.

Comment: Fair point. There are too many unknowns here for a straightforward answer - it's turning into a back-and-forth, which isn't a good format for StackExchange sites